# Why does ASP.NET MVC entity-encode all 8-bit characters > ansi 127?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-encode

Referring to the accepted answer of this question: [ASP.NET - What Characters does Server.HtmlEncode Encode into Named Character Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978673/asp-net-what-characters-does-server-htmlencode-encode-into-named-character-ent)

Here the source code of `HtmlEncode` is cited. I have a question to the following lines:

```
  if ((ch >= '\x00a0') && (ch < 'Ā'))
  {
      output.Write("&#");
      output.Write(ch.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
      output.Write(';');
  }
```

Basically, this transforms all characters from `&nbsp;` (ASCII code 127) to ÿ (ANSI CODE 255) to its entity encoded representation (&#<ansicode>).

All characters with ansi code above 255, though, is just written as is to the output.

Does anyone know the rationale behind this encoding of ANSI 127 - 255? It looks a bit silly to have a webpage, in utf-8, where the source code looks like

```
"S&#248k:"
```

instead of

```
"Søk:"
```

("Søk" is Norwegian for "Search").

Comment: "Not looking silly behind the scenes" isn't the problem that HTML encoding tries to solve - it's for unambiguous representation of content.  Only that range of "Extended ascii" is ambiguous; a character code above 255 *isn't* ascii at all.

Comment: I don't see why ASCII is mentioned at all. Nothing is ASCII here: C# strings are Unicode and HtmlEncode works on these Unicode strings.

Comment: @Codo: ANSI is probably more correct, but 8-bit ASCII is a widely used term, although not technically 100% correct. I edited the original question. I was of course talking about 8-bit character sets, such as iso8859-1 (aka latin-1), etc.

Comment: @Dan Puzey, "extended ascii", or ansi, or whatever we wish to call them, is not ambiguous if you send the correct character encoding with the http/html response, e.g: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Comment: @ErikA.Brandstadmoen: good point, though the question does reference "a webpage in utf-8" specifically.

Comment: @DanPuzey, Yes, I know, which is why it is unnecessary to encode them, as the first 8 bits of UTF-8 is equal to latin-1 (aka iso8859-1) :)

Comment: @ErikA.Brandstadmoen: can you point to a source for that?  I thought there was some overlap between those.

Comment: Sorry, you are actually wrong. Unicode is a superset of latin-1, but UTF-8 use different high-order bits to represent the characters. The lower 8-bit is equal, though... http://jeppesn.dk/utf-8.html

Answer (score 1):

ASCII, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii, only defines the values between 0 and 127; this is 7 bits not 8 bits (a byte).  They are HTML encoding to avoid sending illegal ASCII (The most significant bit on) character.

When sending [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (which is the defacto encoding for the web) the non-ASCII characters (0xA0 - 0xFF) are used to designate multi-byte characters.  So to avoid collisions they are using a named character string.

At least, that's what I would do.

Comment: The upper 127 characters (using 8th bit) of "extended ascii"/ansi 8-bit character set is very well defined in e.g. iso8859-1. And, in unicode, because character 127-255 are the same in Unicode and Latin-1/iso8859-1, so you don't have to entity encode them with numbers...